# Optional [FromServices] in an action method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have a scoped DI service that is optional - settings govern whether it is turned on. For instance this might be a performance tracking overhead we don't want in production, or a third party microservice we want to be able to turn off without a re-release.

With constructor injection I can just check whether the parameter is `null`, but when I try the same pattern in an action method:

```cs
public IActionResult ActionName([FromServices] IOptionalService optionalService)
{
    if(optionalService == null) {
        // handle optional service not being present
    }
    else {
        // do cool stuff with service
        optionalService.DoStuff();
    }
}
```

This throws an exception:

> `No service for type 'TheirNamespace.Whatever.IOptionalService' has been registered.`

The only workaround appears to be a dummy implementation of the service:

```cs
-- startup.cs
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Configuration["UseOptionalService"]))
    services.AddMockService();
else
    services.AddActualService();
```

But this is a pain, as these services may be third party (NuGet packages and the like) or have a lot of methods to implement.

Is this the right way to implement optional DI services? Is there a way to check whether a service has been registered (on startup) in the action method? Is there a better way to turn injected services on and off?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to inject `IServiceProvider` and to use the `GetService` method (not the `GetRequiredService`). Then you can make a null check to see if you get an instance or not.